# Are used Schengen/UK visas acceptable for Turkish e-visa

Tags: visas, turkey, pakistani-citizens, e-visas

I got a UK visa for one month (restricted validity). It expires on November 4. Pakistani citizens are eligible to apply for a Turkish e visa if they have a valid UK visa. I want to visit Istanbul for a couple of days - from October 31 to November 2. Would I be eligible to still apply for an e visa?

My visa is for single entry. It's valid from October 4 to November 4.

Comment: Do you want to visit Istanbul on your way back from UK?

Comment: Yes, on my way back.

Comment: I can visit on my way to the UK as well.

Comment: You should mention the details of your UK visa in the question (Is it single/multi-entry, duration of validity and number of days allowed on visa). Because those details will determine whether your UK visa is valid on the day you intend to enter Turkey after returning from UK.

Comment: Related http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/50287/turkish-evisa-for-schengen-holder-single-entry

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check. There is no mention of the number of days allowed.

Answer (score 7):

There is no restriction for a single entry supporting visa to be **unused** while requesting an eVisa for Turkey. A supporting visa, even if single entry and used is still accepted as long as it is **valid by date** on the date entry is requested into Turkey.

As long as you enter Turkey within the validity period of your Visa (Even if used) you are still eligible for eVisa.

For example if your UK visa expires on 31st December 2017 and it is single entry and you have already used it you can still enter Turkey on 31st December 2017 and then you can stay in Turkey for as long as your eVisa allows.

This is very clearly stated on the **[eVisa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/info/)** website.

> **What are the criteria for the validity of my supporting document (visa or residence permit from Schengen or from US, UK and Ireland)?**
>
> The only requirement for your visa/residence permit to be used as a supporting document is that it should be still valid (by date) by the time you enter Turkey. Previously used or unused single-entry visas are accepted as long as their validity date covers your entry date to Turkey. Please note that e-Visas of other countries are not accepted as a supporting document.

For the sake of completeness, you do not even have to be in Transit to use this visa. It is a tourist visa and you can take a direct flight from your home country to Turkey and back if you like. Whether you go before your UK trip (as in the case of OP) or after, it does not matter. You can make it 2 trips equally as well. One to the UK, one to Turkey.

Comment: I agree with this answer. This February I got Turkish visa from karachi and consulate said the same. Means even with a used visa you can still enter Turkey as long as visa is valid. +1

Comment: +1 from my side too. It seems my existing answer is no longer applicable. Either I wasn't observant enough to look into all FAQs or they have updated the FAQs in the last 1 year. In either case I'll leave a comment in the header of my answer and if OP logs in (not much of a chance) I hope he accepts your answer.