# I have schengen visa till 22nd October and I intend to travel to Turkey on 25th can I apply for e visa and travel

Tags: indian-citizens

I have schengen visa till 22nd October can I apply for Turkey e visa and Travel Turkey after 22nd.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turkish visa for Pakistanis having a UK visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80439/turkish-visa-for-pakistanis-having-a-uk-visa)

Comment: @RedBaron How is a question about a person of unstated nationality who has a Schengen visa a duplicate of a question about a Pakistani with a UK visa?

Comment: Visa rules usually depend on your nationality so we probably can't answer your question without knowing that.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The linked question (despite the reference to nationality) is about validity of a uk/schengen visa for obtaining a Turkish evisa. This question is also about the same. The answer to that question applies totally to this question. Even though the nationalities are different, IMO this is a dup since both nationalitites are eligible for Turkish evisa and rules for obtaining it are same for Indians and Pakistanis. Also  the Indian Citizens tag makes the nationality of OP unambiguous

Comment: @RedBaron Our usual policy here on TSE is that duplicates should be the same question, not a different question that has the same answer. And fair point about the tag, but the information necessary to the question should be in the question itself, not in the indexing metadata.