# Turkey eVisa against Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, turkey, e-visas

I am an Indian citizen. Recently I got a Schengen visa starting 20-03-18. I wanted to travel to Turkey, so I applied for a Turkey eVisa against the Schengen visa. My Turkey visa starting date is 10-03-2018 (ie 10 days earlier than the validity of the Schengen visa). I was not allowed to board the flight for Turkey on 10-03-2018.

Can I travel to Turkey on the same visa within the validity of my Schengen visa?

PS: My Turkey visa validity: 10-03-2018 to 05-10-18. Schengen visa validity: 20-03-2018 to 03-05-2018.

Now I am planning to leave for Athens on 22-03-2018 and enter Turkey on 29-03-2018 until 10-04-2018.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are used Schengen/UK visas acceptable for Turkish e-visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80439/are-used-schengen-uk-visas-acceptable-for-turkish-e-visa)

Comment: @RedBaron it's certainly a similar question, but it's not the same.

Comment: Who did not allow you to board the flight to Turkey and why? The Turkish e-visa previously stipulated you [have to travel on Turkish Air or Pegasus for certain nationalities](http://www.e-visaturkey-tr.com/Requirements.php) `Have a round-trip ticket to Istanbul Ataturk Airport with Turkish Airlines or Pegasus Airlines (applicable only for selected nationalities).` Was that why you were refused boarding? In any case it is unlikely your visa has been voided because it is the airline that denied you boarding.

Answer (score 1):

While your Turkey e-visa has a validity period, during which you can enter the country at any time, that is not the same as *duration of stay.* If that the reason that you were refused boarding, then your revised plan fits within the validity periods of both your Schengen and Turkish visas.

*Enter* Schengen/Athens 22-03-18 *Exit* 29-03-18 
*Enter* Turkey 29-03-18 *Exit* 10-04-18

However, your e-Visa may no longer be acceptable, according to the [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/tour/):

> Once the e-Visa is processed, none of the information on it can be changed. The information on your e-Visa must be exactly the same as the information on your travel document. Otherwise, your e-Visa will be invalid and there will be no refund for it.