# Turkey E-Visa Requirement

Tags: visas, turkey, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani ordinary passport holder. I recently got a 6-month visit visa to the UK and I am traveling there. On my way back, I plan on going to Turkey.

Can I apply for a Turkey E-Visa if I am a Pakistani passport holder with a valid Uk visit visa?

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, You are eligible for an e-Visa.

Here are the requirements listed on the [eVisa](https://www.evisa.gov.tr) website for Pakistani Passport Holders.

> You must meet all the requirements listed below in order to obtain an e-Visa. Please confirm that you meet these criteria by clicking the boxes next to them. If you do not meet any of these requirements and you proceed with your application, your e-Visa will be invalid.
>
> - I am travelling for the purposes of tourism or business.
> - I can prove that I hold a return ticket, hotel reservation and at least 50 $ per each day of my stay.
> - **I have a valid Supporting Document (Valid visa OR valid residence permit from one of the Schengen Countries, USA, UK or Ireland). E-visas are not accepted as supporting documents.**
> - My passport covers the period that I will be staying in Turkey.
> - I confirm that I meet each and every one of the conditions listed above.

(The emphasis is mine)

**Bonus information:**

As of today (2018-06-26), the cost of an eVisa for a Pakistani citizen is **60 USD** (it varies by nationality). And you can get it within **3 minutes**.

**What if the supporting visa was single entry and has already been used?**

A lot of people wonder about that, You are still eligible even if your supporting visa has already been used, as long as it is valid by date when you enter Turkey.

See this answer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/102517/23117

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are eligible for e-Visa, I myself did the same you can visit their website and you will have your e-VISA emailed to your email address within no time. Just take a colour print out of that visa.

The fee is 60 USD plus as you will be using a Pakistani Debit/Credit card you will need to pay an additional 3.5% of bank charges. in Pakistan Rupees, it cost me around 9550 PKR.

Moreover, if you are flying through Turkish Airline and you have a stopover of more than 20 hours you will get a free hotel booking Which I availed.