# Can I enter Turkey or not?

Tags: schengen-visas, turkey

I got Turkey e-visa valid from 18 January,2019 till July,2019 and my Schengen visa from 27 January,2019. Now, Can I travel to Turkey on 25 January, 2019 as I have valid e-visa now? Is there any possibility?

Comment: You have a Turkish e-visa, valid from 18 January 2019 until July 2019. Why do you think you might not be able to enter Turkey on 25 January 2019?

Comment: Because the ticketing agent has mentioned that it is still compulsory that you should have schengen from 25 also thats why I'm confused.

Comment: What is your itinerary?  Are you planning to travel through Schengen countries on your way to Turkey? And what is your citizenship?

Comment: It looks like Turkey's e-visa allows (or requires, in some cases?) a "supporting document" for which a Schengen visa can be used.  Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: @NateEldredge I am planning to go to turkey on 25 January to attend offical meeting there and then after on 27 january fly to belgium. I m from Pakistan.

Comment: Yes. E-visa is obtained with schengen visa as supporting document. But due to difference in dates is there still a possibility that even with e-visa i will be unable to enter turkey?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but have a look at https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80439/are-used-schengen-uk-visas-acceptable-for-turkish-e-visa/102517#102517  The wording on the Turkey visa site is not clear for a visa that is not yet valid, only one that is past validity.