# Applying for Schengen visa to travel to Turkey

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas, turkey

I made a travel plan to visit Turkey on May 1. However, I will not be able to obtain a Turkish sticker visa on time because I failed to procure all required documents on time. Is it okay to now apply for a Schengen visa (let's say, France) from same travel date (starting from May 1) and use it to obtain an e-visa from Turkey?

I understand that I will have to make actual flight and hotel bookings to apply for the Schengen visa. My main concern is, is it completely okay if I don't use my Schengen visa to visit Europe but Turkey from May 1?

Clarification: I am planning to obtain a Schengen visa from May 1 to 10 (with a proper EU itinerary). However, I will actually visit Turkey from May 1 to 10. Is this wrong in any way?

** The processing time for w Turkish visa is 10 days, whereas for France it is 2 days. That's my motivation to apply for a Schengen visa in the given available time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are used Schengen/UK visas acceptable for Turkish e-visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/80439/are-used-schengen-uk-visas-acceptable-for-turkish-e-visa)

Comment: @Traveller: I don't think so, my concern is that I am applying for French (Schengen) visa with all proper docs saying that I will be visiting Paris from May 1 to 10, however, I will be using that Schengen visa to obtain Turkey e-Visa to visit Istanbul. Are you clear with my question now?

Answer (score 4):

You will not get a visa from the French consulate unless you claim that you have plans to visit France and describe those plans in some detail.

If those plans are ones you don't actually intend to follow even approximately, then that means you are **lying in a visa application**, which is extremely not recommended. Possibly your chance of the lie being *found out* is small(ish), but *if* it is found out, you'll have ruined your chances of getting any Schengen visa for a long, long time.

Is that really worth it? There are 18 days until May 1, so if you expect the Turkish consulate to process an application in 10 days, that should be plenty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I include a small travel itinerary to an European country (say Greece/France) from Istanbul between May 1 to 10, can I apply for Schengen visa from Greece for the entire duration of May 1 to 10? FYI, my visa cannot be processed by Turkish consulate in given time due to national/election holidays in my country.