# Wanted to apply for Turkish evisa

Tags: visas, turkey

Turkey allows evisa facility for Indians with valid Schengen visas. I have a Schengen visa on my passport but it has expired.  Does that still allow me to apply for evisa to Turkey ?

Answer (score 3):

No, it explicitely says Valid visa, or variant on the e-visa page of Tr (https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/prerequisites/). Therefore, I'd argue an expired Schengen visa won't work and you shouldn't attempt it.

Comment: This is incorrect. Please see https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/102517/50234

Comment: The visa has expired, meaning its valid date is over (that's how I interpret it), that's what appears explicitely in the answer you linked : it's not a matter of visa being used or not, but expired or not which is the case here. So this doesn't contradict my answer, only reinforces it ?

Comment: Ah my bad, i jumped the gun a bit